# jQuery mouseover on SVG path - Strange bug

Tags: jquery, svg, mousehover

Good evening,

I'm coding a site for my orchestra and I am implementing an organization chart with pictures. My idea is to have a "map" of all seats in the orchestra and when you hover over one of the seats with your mouse, information about this person will pop out. I got that to work thanks to a little bit of jQuery and an SVG tweak :

```
<g id="luc" class="Seats">
      <path class="cls-9" d="M441.6,153.2l-6.23,13.41L429.15,180a3.4,3.4,0,0,0,.56,3.71l3.11,3.46,3.11,3.46a3.4,3.4,0,0,0,3.63.94l14-4.82,14-4.82a3.4,3.4,0,0,0,1.42-5.49l-10.85-12-10.85-12a3.4,3.4,0,0,0-5.61.84Z" transform="translate(-10.26 -9.14)" />
</g>
<g id="hugo" class="Seats">
      <path class="cls-9" d="M478.17,197.79,468.49,209l-9.68,11.18a3.4,3.4,0,0,0-.49,3.72l2,4.18,2,4.18a3.4,3.4,0,0,0,3.24,1.9l14.75-.78,14.75-.78a3.4,3.4,0,0,0,2.87-4.88L490.9,213.1l-7.11-14.57a3.4,3.4,0,0,0-5.62-.74Z" transform="translate(-10.26 -9.14)" />
</g>
<g id="maxime_d" class="Seats">
      <path class="cls-9" d="M501,250.74l-12.39,8.07-12.39,8.07a3.4,3.4,0,0,0-1.49,3.44l.81,4.58.81,4.58a3.4,3.4,0,0,0,2.58,2.72l14.4,3.31,14.4,3.31a3.4,3.4,0,0,0,4.11-3.9l-2.82-16-2.82-16a3.4,3.4,0,0,0-5.2-2.26Z" transform="translate(-10.26 -9.14)" />
</g>
<g id="marie" class="Seats">
      <path class="cls-8" d="M320.57,318.25l-5.8-13.6L309,291a3.4,3.4,0,0,0-3.13-2.07h-9.3a3.4,3.4,0,0,0-3.13,2.07l-5.76,13.6-5.76,13.6A3.4,3.4,0,0,0,285,323h32.43a3.4,3.4,0,0,0,3.13-4.73Z" transform="translate(-10.26 -9.14)" />
</g>
```

These `path`s correspond to (in order) 4,3,2,1 seats on the following picture :

[image: Picture]

My problem is that the mouseover works perfectly on seats 1 and 2 (the picture pop up exactly when I touch the seat), but do not cover the entire seat on 3 and 4.

I have no idea what causes this problem, which happens on Chrome, Firefox and Edge...

My jQuery code :

```
$(".Seats").hover(over, out); 

function animateOver(element) {
    console.log(element);
    var tl = new TimelineLite();
    var select = $(element);
    var name = select.attr('name');

    $("#name_display").html(name);

    tl.timeScale(1);
    tl.to($("#" + element.id + "_card"), 1, { opacity: 1 });
    tl.to($("#name_display"), 1, { opacity: 1 }, '-=1');
    tl.play();
    return tl;
}

function over() {
    //check if this item has an animation
    if (!this.animation) {
        //if not, create one
        this.animation = animateOver(this);
    } else {
        //or else play it
        this.animation.play().timeScale(1);
    }
}

function out() {
    //reverse animation 4 times normal speed
    this.animation.reverse().timeScale(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where my problem was : the pictures that pops up (when I put my mouse over the seats) were actually still there with an opacity of zero and were blocking the detection of the "overing" !